# Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql problem when access property

Tags: mysql, .net-6.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Today I migrate my project to .NET 6 with MySql db.
I tried Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql for the first time but several errors had occur.
I fixed some of them but the last one, I couldn`t.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'SqlClass.Disabled' is of type 'byte' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

             entity.Property(e => e.Disabled)
           //.HasConversion<int>()
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .HasColumnName("disabled")
            .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public byte Disabled { get; set; }
```

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you migrating from what?

Comment: .NET 3.1 To .NET 6

Comment: The error is pretty clear, byte doesn't exists in MySQL.

Comment: But how to convert this property to working one like int or bool ?
I tried with .HasConversion<int>() onModelCreating but no effect at all.

Comment: What do you save? a bool?  From wich database are you migrating?

Comment: I was using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore  by Oracle 8.0.20.
for provider on .net core 3.1 but when I updated to .net6 this nuget was deprecated . I was forced to install new nuget package, alternate package not worked for me. Then I decide to install Pomelo, and that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically **3 simple options**, all demonstrated here with the `IceCream.Available` property:

---

### 1. Use `System.Boolean` instead of `System.Byte`

Pomelo translates `tinyint(1)` to `System.Boolean` by default. So if you change the CLR type of your property from `byte` to `bool`, it works out-of-the box:

##### Program.cs

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "tinyint(1)")] // <-- redundant (bool is translated to tinyint(1) by default)
        public bool Available { get; set; } // <-- use bool
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So70198786";
            var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    // Not needed if you are using data annotations:
                    //
                    // entity.Property(e => e.Available)
                    //     .IsRequired()
                    //     .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)"); // <-- redundant (bool is translated to tinyint(1) by default)

                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCream
                        {
                            IceCreamId = 1,
                            Name = "Vanilla",
                            Available = true, // <-- bool
                        },
                        new IceCream
                        {
                            IceCreamId = 2,
                            Name = "Chocolate",
                            Available = false, // <-- bool
                        });
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var availableIceCreams = context.IceCreams
                .Where(i => i.Available) // <-- bool
                .ToList();
            
            Trace.Assert(availableIceCreams.Count == 1);
            Trace.Assert(availableIceCreams[0].Name == "Vanilla");
        }
    }
}
```

##### Output (SQL)

```sql
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
      Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data; this mode should only be enabled during development.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql:6.0.0-rtm.1' with options: ServerVersion 8.0.25-mysql SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled DetailedErrorsEnabled
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (38ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DROP DATABASE `So70198786`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE DATABASE `So70198786`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (47ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `IceCreams` (
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `Available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
      ) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Available`, `Name`)
      VALUES (1, TRUE, 'Vanilla');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Available`, `Name`)
      VALUES (2, FALSE, 'Chocolate');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Available`, `i`.`Name`
      FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
      WHERE `i`.`Available`
```

---

### 2. Use `tinyint` instead of `tinyint(1)`

In case you definitely want to use `System.Byte` as the CLR type of your property, use `tinyint` instead of `tinyint(1)`. All `tinyint` except `tinyint(1)` are translated to `System.Byte` by default:

##### Program.cs

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "tinyint")] // <-- redundant (byte is translated to tinyint by default)
        public byte Available { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So70198786_01";
            var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    // Not needed if you are using data annotations:
                    //
                    // entity.Property(e => e.Available)
                    //     .IsRequired()
                    //     .HasColumnType("tinyint"); // <-- redundant (byte is translated to tinyint by default)

                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCream
                        {
                            IceCreamId = 1,
                            Name = "Vanilla",
                            Available = 1, // <-- byte
                        },
                        new IceCream
                        {
                            IceCreamId = 2,
                            Name = "Chocolate",
                            Available = 0, // <-- byte
                        });
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var availableIceCreams = context.IceCreams
                .Where(i => i.Available != 0) // <-- byte
                .ToList();
            
            Trace.Assert(availableIceCreams.Count == 1);
            Trace.Assert(availableIceCreams[0].Name == "Vanilla");
        }
    }
}
```

##### Output (SQL)

```sql
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
      Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data; this mode should only be enabled during development.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql:6.0.0-rtm.1' with options: ServerVersion 8.0.25-mysql SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled DetailedErrorsEnabled
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (42ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DROP DATABASE `So70198786_01`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (41ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE DATABASE `So70198786_01`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (48ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `IceCreams` (
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `Available` tinyint NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
      ) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Available`, `Name`)
      VALUES (1, 1, 'Vanilla');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Available`, `Name`)
      VALUES (2, 0, 'Chocolate');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Available`, `i`.`Name`
      FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
      WHERE `i`.`Available` <> 0
```

---

### 3. Change default `System.Boolean` mapping to `bit(1)` or remove it altogether

Finally, if you need to map exactly `tinyint(1)` to `System.Byte`, then you can change the default mapping that Pomelo is using for `System.Boolean` by setting a `DbContext` option in your `UseMySql()` call:

#### Program.cs

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "tinyint(1)")] // <-- necessary (otherwise gets translated to tinyint)
        public byte Available { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So70198786_02";
            var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    connectionString,
                    serverVersion,
                    options => options.DefaultDataTypeMappings( // <-- change default data type mappings
                        m => m.WithClrBoolean(MySqlBooleanType.Bit1))) // <-- or even MySqlBooleanType.None
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    // Not needed if you are using data annotations:
                    //
                    // entity.Property(e => e.Available)
                    //     .IsRequired()
                    //     .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)"); // <-- necessary (otherwise gets translated to tinyint)

                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCream
                        {
                            IceCreamId = 1,
                            Name = "Vanilla",
                            Available = 1, // <-- byte
                        },
                        new IceCream
                        {
                            IceCreamId = 2,
                            Name = "Chocolate",
                            Available = 0, // <-- byte
                        });
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var availableIceCreams = context.IceCreams
                .Where(i => i.Available != 0) // <-- byte
                .ToList();
            
            Trace.Assert(availableIceCreams.Count == 1);
            Trace.Assert(availableIceCreams[0].Name == "Vanilla");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output (SQL)

```sql
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
      Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data; this mode should only be enabled during development.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql:6.0.0-rtm.1' with options: ServerVersion 8.0.25-mysql SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled DetailedErrorsEnabled
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (40ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DROP DATABASE `So70198786_02`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE DATABASE `So70198786_02`;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (86ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `IceCreams` (
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `Available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
      ) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Available`, `Name`)
      VALUES (1, 1, 'Vanilla');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `Available`, `Name`)
      VALUES (2, 0, 'Chocolate');
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`Available`, `i`.`Name`
      FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
      WHERE `i`.`Available` <> 0
```

---

Unrelated to the topic of this question, `[MaxLength(255)]` or `.HasMaxLength(255)` have no effect on non-string columns.